# Problem installing the ADT Plugin for Eclipse

Tags: android

I am trying to build an Android development environment on my PC. But I'm encountering some problems, and desperately need help.
Operating System: **Windows 7 (64 bit)**
Installed components:

- Android SDK  (installer_r12-windows)
- Eclipse Classic 3.7 for Windows 64 bit

I am trying to install the ADT Plugin for Eclipse but I'm having some trouble with it.
I tried following the instructions listed on the official site (http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) but without success.
I first tried setting the location for the new repository to

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

as suggested, but I got the following error message:

> Unable to connect to repository
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/content.xml

(I tried using "http" instead of "https" but got the same results).

I then tried as suggested to download the ADT Plugin zip file, and set the location of the new repository to the local copy I downloaded. But, this time I couldn't go through with the installation because 'Android DDMS' caused the following problem:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software being installed: Android Development Tools
>   12.0.0.v201106281929-138431 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group
>   12.0.0.v201106281929-138431)

Can someone help?

Comment: Please check that you have both java 32 and 64 bit installed, i ended up using 32 bit

Comment: I recomonded you for use [eclipse java Eclipse IDE for Java Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) then try again for Android ADT.

Comment: I downloaded 'Eclipse IDE for Java Developers' but it made no difference.

Comment: Same problem here. Following instructions at http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html which says to install Eclipse Classic and set up repository with URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Doesn't work. Documentation is wrong or Eclipse is broken.

Comment: I had the same problem. Firewall caused it. Afrer shutting down everything works.

Comment: This might be the firewall issue. just `turn off` your firewall and then try to `install adt` plug in.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of the repository being

`https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/content.xml`

it should be

`https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/site.xml`

If you manually download the ZIP, you have to do a manual install (install the ZIP plugin, don't set the repository to the ZIP).  I suggest doing it through the URL, though, so you automatically get updates.

Comment: I tried changing the repository location to [link](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/site.xml), but I got the following error message:
Unable to connect to repository https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/site.xml/compositeContent.xml
Connection timed out: connect
What is the problem?

Comment: It sounds like it is automatically adding "content.xml" to the end of the URL.  Is eclipse completely up-to-date?  Maybe there is a checkbox that stops the auto-guessing?  I don't use eclipse, so I can't give you exact instructions from there.

Comment: I've downloaded the latest addition of Eclips (version 3.7). What are the alternatives to Eclipse?

Comment: I use Netbeans for Android development.

Answer (score 4):

`Eclipse -> Window -> Preferences -> General -> Network` and unchecked my system’s proxies by choosing direct connection.

I was connected using a proxy, but it worked better in direct connection.

Comment: @Yousif I recommend you to use Android Studio, soon Google will stop supporting eclipse

Answer (score 2):

i had the same trouble. 
I have windows 7 64 bit.
At first look I installed JDK 7.02 64 bit, and after this article I installed JDK 7.02 32 bit too and the now http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ works correctly!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

disable antivirus and firewall. run eclipse as administrator.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the issue is solved. For me it was'nt working with Win7, Ubuntu and Linux Mint.

On Win7 it directly works when I started Eclipse with '-vmargs -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true' . Seems like there is something not working with the IP6 Stack - so you have to force Eclipse to use the IP4 one.

I will look if it solves this problem under LinuxMint/Ubuntu(if issue pops up again).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on windows 7 , solving it with changing the network connection to "Direct" from :

**Window > Preferences > General > Network connection**

changing active provider to Direct .

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes all the tape and glue doesn't hold together and you need some extra files. If you have eclipse classic you can go to the install new software option in help and select the indigo repository and select mobile and device development. Then you should be able to have everything up and running

Answer (score 0):

There is many options why this doesn't work. But once you covered the other network problems/suggestions, this is what you should try. If everything is ok with your network connection, it should work:
- uncheck the "Contact all update sites during install to find required software"
- in the URL to the repository, use http instead of https.

Answer (score 0):

try this brother, worked with me 100%:

```
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
```

this is http:// and yours http's'://
[image]

good luck