# Connecting Eclipse Helios and Android Plugin in Windows 7 (32-

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, helios, adk

I installed **Eclipse Helios** Software. And i also downloaded **Android SDK Manager**. I installed some in the SDK. When I click on **Help---> Install New Software** and click the "Add" button. I was asked the Name and the Location. I gave the Name as ADT Plugin and Location as "https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/". But its showing that the link is not found in the **repository**. I should create an Android Project. How should I do this?

Comment: Did you try the non secure url? change https to http

Comment: First I tried using https. but it shows thats a duplicate link. so i tried http. yet i faced the problrm.

Comment: Please help me out guys...

Answer (score 0):

under the settings menu in miscellaneous section check- Force https://… sources to be fetched using http://… and retry.. i think it might help..

Answer (score 0):

read the troubleshooting installation at 
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html
it  clearly says

*If Eclipse can not find the remote update site containing the ADT plugin, try changing the remote site URL to use http, rather than https. That is, set the Location for the remote site 
to:
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

*If you are using firewall make sure to make certain settings regarding proxy...

here is also good discussion about your question
[Problem installing the ADT Plugin for Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164642/problem-installing-the-adt-plugin-for-eclipse)